# Multiple applications from the same Codeigniter code installation for multiple customer

Tags: php, codeigniter

My product has 50 customers. Each customer has a MYSQL database and I am using Codeigniter.

I have 50 subfolders e.g domain.com/client1 domain.com/client2 and so on 
I want to have only one installation for all my customers and different database and subdomain
I dont want multiple copy of installation for each new client

Ideally domain.com/app/

What is the best way to achieve this?
I tried dynamically creating folder for each customer and writing diff config file when customer register with us.
I think I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Can you tell us the reason for wanting a different database for each customer? Sometimes there are better ways to approach this if you do not need to have a separate database for each customer. You might be required to have this for security and data separation, but it would be useful to know.

Comment: I want to keep record for each customer that why I am want different database

Comment: Does your application has authentication for each of those customers ?

Comment: yes I have maintained track of each customer

Comment: is only the database different and everything else (besides the url) is the same ?

Comment: suppose my url is domain.com then for customer it will be domain.com/client1, domain.com/client2

Comment: yes everything except db is same

Comment: @shine note that you make life easier for the people willing to help you if you provide a [mcve]

Comment: Useful link for this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/manage-multiple-applications-in-codeigniter--cms-29795

Answer (score 3):

What you want is something like multi-tenancy architecture i.e same code for all customer but dedicated database for each of them.

**1)**  What you can do is you can create a master database to record the user and its associated database. Once the user is registered with you  create a fresh database for them and update the master table, record the database name associated with that user.

**2)** When user logins you need to authenticate with master table data,once authenticated you have the database name associated with user.
Once you have the database name you need to switch database to the user's database.
There is function available in CodeIgniter, where you can update `$db` variable:

```
$this->db = $this->load->database();
```

Once done than all operation will be perform to related user's database only.

**NOTE** : You will need to change `$db` variable at all required files or you can change it globally.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

To load the database globally you can save the database in session and in helper file create a function (use the database name from session) which will switch the database. You just need to load the helper in the main controller this will switch `$db` globally.

Comment: Is it possible to change db variable globally and if how?

Comment: @shine : Please check edit part of my answer.